# Цвет слова в тексте в JTextPane

Tags: java

Пытаюсь сделать подсветку определённых слов в JTextPane. Слово подсвечивается, но отделяется от остальной части строки. Вот скриншот:

[image: снимок]

Код:

```
private void addToTextArea(final String text) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                StyledDocument doc = jTextPane1.getStyledDocument();
                StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
                AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.BLACK);
                aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.Bold, true);
                aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.Family, "Arial");
                int len = doc.getLength();
                    AttributeSet aset2 = aset;
                    aset2 = sc.addAttribute(aset2, StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.BLUE);

                    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), text + "\n", aset);
                int at = text.indexOf("[INFO]");
                if (at > -1) {
                    doc.setCharacterAttributes(len + at+3, 6, aset2, false);
                }
                jTextPane1.getDocument().insertString(jTextPane1.getDocument().getLength(), text + "\n", null);
            } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

В чём ошибка и как это можно исправить?

Comment: Почему бы сразу не указывать вставляемому тексту правильный attribute set? И почему вы добавляете текста дважды?

Comment: И, кстати, не отделяется, а явно теряется \\n почему-то

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, не знаю, что вы там творите, но вот же всё работает как надо

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private static AttributeSet mySet;
    private static JTextPane textPane;

    public Frame() {

        super("test");

        textPane = new JTextPane();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(textPane);

        mySet = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext().addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.BLUE);

        try {
            addLine("Hello");
            addLine("[INFO] wwef");
            addLine("Hello");
        } catch (BadLocationException ignore) {
        }

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setSize(800, 600);
    }

    private static void addLine(String text) throws BadLocationException {
        textPane.getStyledDocument().insertString(textPane.getStyledDocument().getLength(), text + "\n", text.contains("[INFO]") ? mySet : null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Пример немного не тот, но я исправил, всё действительно работает... Спасибо, буду разбираться, что у меня не так.